# How to control UIMenuController, in case I do not want it hide automatically?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uitextfield, uimenucontroller

I'm doing a chat tool, with a `UITextField` as input. The problem is, when other UI control updates, like messages scroll on new arrivals, the `UIMenuController`, if currently visible,  automatically hides. How can I forbid such automation?
Even I can catch the event with `UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification` or `UIMenuControllerDidHideMenuNotification`, there's no way I can control it.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try its instance method

```
setMenuVisible:(BOOL)menuVisible animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: I tried. Though it can control the visibility elsewhere, it cannot cancel an auto-hide in the UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification event handler.